# DELETE*FROM table

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, sql, sql-server

Is there a way (similar to the below code) to delete all the rows in a specified table using c#?

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conString);
con.Open();

string sql = @"DELETE*FROM compsTickers;";
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, con);
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
con.Close();
```

Right now i'm getting an error:

> Incorrect syntax near '*'

Comment: When you get a syntax error in SQL, it is always a good idea to execute the offending SQL directly against the database (for SQL Server this will be using Management Studio/Query Analyzer); this should highlight where the problem is, or at least show you that the problem is not with your C# code, but with the SQL itself.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with your C# code; that's an SQL syntax error.

Anyway, there's no need for the `*`. You delete *rows*, not *columns*, from a table, so you don't specify columns to delete:

```sql
DELETE FROM compsTickers
```

Comment: As explained by Mark Redman under cairnz's answer, if you're looking to reset your identities while emptying your table, you should use `TRUNCATE TABLE` instead.

Answer (score 16):

You don't specify columns `DELETE FROM compsTickers` is enough.

(Also `TRUNCATE TABLE compsTickers` will do, it's a different way of deletion, that could make sense depending on your transaction log settings)

Comment: is there a reason there's no need for a *?

Comment: Truncate will also reset IDENTITY fields, which may or may not be desired.

Comment: @cfarm54 - you delete a complete row - there's never a "partial" delete. You can `UPDATE` however to blank out certain columns, or set to NULL or whatever you wish.

Comment: +1 for truncate, which is usually faster and resets the identity fields.

Answer (score 10):

Just remove the `*` as it isn't needed to for `DELETE` statements

`string sql = @"DELETE FROM compsTickers;";`

Answer (score 3):

[DELETE (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189835.aspx) (link)

FROM is optional.  You're always DELETing from a table, so all you needed was (you don't even need a statement delimiter, for a single statement):

```
DELETE compsTickers
```

Which empties the table

- but does not reset the identity column, if any

Comment: Is the optional `FROM` clause a T-SQL thing or part of standard ANSI SQL?

Comment: It's SQL Server only (I linked to Books Online instead of SQL92 reference) but my crystal ball tells me that is what the OP is using.

Comment: Looks like it. I'm just curious, is all :) +1

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest to use the

1. Stored Procedure to perform all the operation .
2. You must always avoid Hard Coded string in Code.
3. Manage the Transaction in case you need to revert back the changes.

Comment: This is in a clear database method so maybe it's ok in this case?

Answer (score 0):

```
string sql = @"DELETE FROM compsTickers;";
```

You don't need to use a `*` or specify any column name in the delete statement.

Answer (score 0):

Writing '*' in the delete query is not a good Practice. Since we are not deleting columns, we are actually deleting rows from the table.

The * refers to all columns in the table. Try to use the following syntax
'Delete from compsTickers' followed by where condition.

Answer (score 0):

The syntax of the delete command is not correct. You are not required to use `'*'` in delete command. Use command `string sql = @"DELETE FROM compsTickers;"` for your job.

Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conString);
con.close();
cmd=new SqlCommand("DELETE FROM compsTickers", con);
con.Open();
int i = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
if(i>0)
{
 MessageBox.Show("Successful.");
}
con.Close();
```

Comment: `con.close()` will not compile and why are you trying to close a new connection? `i` will be zero if the table is empty so `i == 0` is a success.

Comment: i  always pass the connection string globally, here its just to show that connection string exists.

Answer (score -2):

The error seams to happen because no spaces before and after '*' (should have been ' * ').

Comment: There should be no `*` at all.